# Why are there curly braces around item?

Tags: react-native-flatlist

What is the purpose of the curly braces around `item` in the `renderItem` prop? I've tried passing it in like so

```
renderItem={ item => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Kindly guide me for this.

```
//Code snippet from React Native docs as below.
//url: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Dan'},
            {key: 'Dominic'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: 22
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})
```

Comment: I'm surprised no one has answered this.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is object destructing; an ES6 feature. Look it up. The actual object passed to the function you define in `renderItem` is not your actual item array. It's actually and object that has your item inside it for example `{a: ..., b: ... , item: /*your item*/}`. object destructing allows you to specify the parameter of the function as one of the objects inside the actual object that's passed in.

E.g

```
function printName({name}) {
  console.log(name)
}
obj = {age: 32, name: 'Alex'}

printName(obj);
```

this will print 'Alex'

What makes it confusing is the fact that destructing syntax uses curly braces and so does the JSX parser... but the curly braces mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

It's to extract the values of item , that's how JSX works. If there would have been only item , i.e `<Text>item</Text>` then it will render item as the output , but if you want to display the value of item , suppose `item =50`, then display `<Text>{item}</Text>` so 50 will be displayed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but it's not quite what I meant. I was referring to this bit:

```
renderItem={(**{item}**) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
```